# Apex 5.0 Filling Region with Help Text of another Page

Tags: session, url, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

**Is there a way to let a help text region (APEX 5.0) show the help text of another page?**

I created a help page 0 (as modal dialog) in APEX 5.0, which is reachable by clicking a Navigation Bar List Entry.
The page itself has only one Region, which shall display the Help Text of the Page it was called from. The ID of the calling Page is transmitted into a hidden item via URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You can get the Help Text of a page anywhere in your application. You can use this query as a source of your item that will display the help text:

```
  select HELP_TEXT
     from APEX_APPLICATION_PAGES
     where APPLICATION_ID = yourappid and 
           PAGE_ID = pagenumber_of_the_helptext_you_want_toget
```

Comment: thanks, works for me. had to fill a interactive report with this, since the actual help text region isnt fillable with specific content